# Upload file via Soap message using MTOM in iOS

Tags: ios, soap, attachment, mtom, xop

I have found here [Upload file via Soap message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929626/ios-soap-nsurlconnection-and-upload-a-file) in detail. But i have another issue if there is large file in Soap then it creates memory issues cause of file loads in memory for sending via *Soap message*.

I read about MTOM (Message Transmission Optimisation Mechanism). "When you use MTOM/XOP to optimise a *SOAP message*, the *XOP* processing serialises it into a MIME Multipart/Related message. The XOP processing extracts the *base64Binary* data from the *SOAP message* and packages it as separate binary attachments within the *MIME* message, in a similar manner to e-mail attachments"

I have found how to use this approach in java here [Soap with Attachments and MTOM in Java](http://www.javaexperience.com/soap-with-attachments-and-mtom/)

Now i have *two questions* :-

1. By using *MTOM/XOP* approach in **iOS** we can reduce Or solve the
   issue of memory as explaind above.
2. In programming How we can use *MTOM/XOP* approach in **iOS**.

Any help will be appriciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have the same question. Hope someone can answer this.

Comment: someone managed to get attachments in iOS?

Comment: any Update on this question ? has someone got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done same request using the Rest Kit.Rest kit allows to send attachment in MTOM Specification.

First thing you need is to download Restkit.

Following is the code snippet for the MTOM using the RestKit.

```
abv.h 
    #import "RestKit/RestKit.h"
    RKObjectManager *man;
    RKObjectLoader *loader;   

abc.m

     RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
    //Start Progress bar
    RKParams * params = [[RKParams alloc] init];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"zbar-samples.png"];
    RKObjectManager *man;
    NSData * fileData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.7);


    [params setValue:@"1234" forParam:@"encryptedToken"];
    [params setValue:modelObj.docNameTobeSent
            forParam:@"documentName"];
    RKParamsAttachment * attachments = [params setData:fileData forParam:@"file"];
    [attachments setMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
    [attachments setFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",modelObj.name]];
    self.man = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:YOUR URL];
    self.loader = [self.man loadObjectsAtResourcePathUsingPOSTRPC:@"upload.form"    objectMapping:nil PostParams:params delegate:self];



     - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
    {
    //Handle fail error
    //stop Progress bar
    }

    - (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects
    {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"didLoadObjects");
    }
    - (void)objectLoaderDidFinishLoading:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"objectLoaderDidFinishLoading");
    //stop Progress bar
    }
    - (void)objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"objectLoaderDidLoadUnexpectedResponse");
    //stop Progress bar
    }
```

Comment: Do you know the the difference between SOAP request and rest request ? i am asking here about SOAP request with MTOM not via REST.....

Comment: For SOAP you can see the below link        http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts.webservices.doc%2Fmtomxop%2Fdfhws_attachments_and_SOAP.html